# After installed horizon (Openstack Train), When access http://controller_ip/dashboard, Got error “/auth/login/ was not found on this server”

Tags: openstack

I installed the Openstack horizon(Train version) by followed [guide](https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/train/install/install-rdo.html), no error showing in my install steps. After finished install, I access "*http://controller_ip/dashboard*", and got an error:

> The requested URL /auth/login/ was not found on this server.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

this
https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1853651

By adding the following to the config file (and restarting httpd), the horizon dashboard then loads without issue:

```
WEBROOT = '/dashboard'
```